# Looking for Virtual PC or VMware Guest O/S with Linux already installed

Tags: vmware, virtual-pc

I wanted to play around with Linux and do some testing.  I've tried installing Linux on a Virtual PC (2004) guest but couldn't get it to work.

I figured with all the folks out there proselytizing about Linux maybe someone had made an guess file that I could just download and open up in Virtual PC (ideally) or VmWare.

PS - I asked question on ExpertsExchange about 2 years ago and all I got was people telling me I should use VMware (but not suggestions of where to find a pre-made Guest record.)

Comment: Why do you prefer virtual pc over vmware (out of curiosity)?

Comment: Because I already have Virtual PC intalled. VPC is free. My understanding is that VMWare is free but only for the *player* and that if I want to create, say, an image with Windows XP, that I'd have to buy the Server. FYI, I use Virtualizing only for testing.

Comment: http://www.vmware.com/products/server/ is free, but it is a bit heavier of an application than Virtual PC.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

VMware player: http://www.vmware.com/products/player/

Vmware images: http://www.vmware.com/appliances/

The appliances website was down for me, but you can download premade images of various operating systems and run them using the vmware player or vmware server.

Ubuntu 8.04: http://www.vmware.com/appliances/directory/1224

Also, just look at the popular section on the right-hand side.  I have found that when you want to use Linux, vmware is the way to go.  I have had issues trying to install it on virtual pc, but that might have changed since I tried it back in 2006 with Fedora.

Answer (score 4):

The VMWare library of pre-installed guests is at http://www.vmware.com/appliances/ - it seems to be currently down for maintenance though.

Comment: Darn...I had mine finished, but I was looking at vmware converter to see if it could convert vmware images to virtual pc before I submitted it.

Comment: Tip from Joel (on the SO podcast) - just post your answer immediately then EDIT it.

Answer (score 1):

The VMWare appliance site is down as I write this but there is a very useful appliance that is about 60K that allows you to mount an ISO as a VM.

This is great because you don't have to install the distribution in a VM. You can load up the ISO into the VM every time as new or simply reload a suspended image.

When you feel comfortable - try installing the version of Linux in the VM.

You could also simply burn an ISO to a CD/DVD and boot it up to play with it - no install required.

You should also take a look at Sun's VirtualBox VM manager. Its free and pretty good.

Answer (score 0):

Try http://elasticserver.com/

They have a a la carte approach for linux VM's.

Answer (score 0):

Virtual Hosted Linux is a pain. If you MUST do this, then use [Sun's VirtualBox](http://www.virtualbox.org/) - it starts up faster and really is easier to use than anything else .. You can get Ready To Use VDI images from [VirtualBoxImages](http://virtualboximages.com/veedeeeyes/About) too... But, if you just wanna 'play around' with linux, then why not boot up a [LiveCD](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LiveCD) ..